# Background Image not appearing in XCODE 12

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have a Zstack within ContentView in xcode I'm attempting to add a background image to. This image is intended to serve as the background for the entire screen, but it does not show up. The image is saved in xcassets with the correct label for the code below. This has been double, no triple-checked.

My code:

```
import SwiftUI
import CoreData

struct ContentView: View {
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) private var viewContext
    
    @State var phoneNumberCompleted = false;
    @State var phoneNumber = ""
    
    @FetchRequest(
        sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \Item.timestamp, ascending: true)],
        animation: .default)
    private var items: FetchedResults<Item>

    var body: some View
    {
        ZStack
        {
            
           
            
                NavigationView
                {
                    
                    Form
                    {
                        Section(header: Text("Account Credentials"))
                        {
                            TextField("Phone Number", text: $phoneNumber)
                                
                              
                            if phoneNumberCompleted
                            {
                                Button(action: {
                                    
                                }) {
                                    
                                        HStack
                                        {
                                            Spacer()
                                          
                                            Text("Log in")
                                              
                                                .font(.system(size: 20))
                                            .padding(2)
                                            .background(Color.red)
                                            .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                                            .cornerRadius(10)
                                                .shadow(color: Color.gray, radius: 2)
                                            Spacer()
                                        
                                        }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        Section(header: Text("ABOUT APP"))
                        {
                            HStack
                            {
                               
                                Text("Version")
                                Spacer()
                                Text("0.0.1")
                            }
                        }
                        
                    }
                    .navigationBarTitle("Welcome to Mapwork")
                    
                }
        }.background(Image("bg"))
        .opacity(100)
    }
}
```

I'm wondering if I am using the correct approach or if something is wrong here. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you need to add the code below to make the background clear:

```
init() {
    UITableView.appearance().backgroundColor = .clear
}
```

Then you can add your background without a problem and here it is the result:

```
        .navigationBarTitle("Welcome to Mapwork")
        .background(Image("image1"))
```

Note: I don't know why are you using `opacity` anyway, for your information the opacity value it must be between `0` and `1`.

[image: result]

Comment: Can you please be more clear about where to add the additional code? I am new to IOS development.

Comment: you add between struct and body